# How to Filter out values in excel spreadsheet based on a day

Tags: excel-formula

I have table in this form....

```
 Date:  User ID:
 02/11/2015 9:02    1283577 
 02/11/2015 9:03    1006768
 02/11/2015 9:03    1006768
 02/11/2015 9:03    1006768
 02/11/2015 9:09    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:09    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:10    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:10    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:11    1006824
 02/11/2015 9:11    1006824
 02/11/2015 9:11    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:11    1284033
 02/11/2015 9:12    1006824
 02/11/2015 9:12    1006824
 02/11/2015 9:27    45838
 02/11/2015 9:27    45838
 02/11/2015 9:27    45838
 02/11/2015 9:28    45838
 02/11/2015 9:28    45838
```

To get something like this....

```
Date:           User ID:
02/11/2015 9:02 1283577
02/11/2015 9:03 1006768
02/11/2015 9:10 1284033
02/11/2015 9:11 1006824
02/11/2015 9:11 1284033
02/11/2015 9:12 1006824
02/11/2015 9:28 45838
```

Basically remove all rows where user ID is duplicate for that day. I have data for few months so this is just part of it...

Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is located at `A1:B19` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

To extract only the date enter this formula in `C1` the copy till last record

`=INT(A1)`

Then in `D1` enter this formula and copy till last record

`=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B2,$B2,$C$1:$C2,$C2)=1,"Ok","Duplicated")`

[image]

Comment: That would probably work but I had this idea about grouping data into intervals first....for example is it possible to do this.....

Comment: 02/11/2015 9:03  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:00 AM
    02/11/2015 9:09      to something like this 02/11/2015 9:15 AM
    02/11/2015 9:10  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:15 AM
    02/11/2015 9:11  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:15 AM
    02/11/2015 9:11  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:15 AM
    02/11/2015 9:12  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:15 AM
    02/11/2015 9:27  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:30 AM
    02/11/2015 9:28  to something like this 02/11/2015  9:30 AM

Comment: Did you tried? What do you mean with probably work. It works it's tested. What's the point about grouping it first, what that will achieve?

Comment: Yes it worked. The only thing is that i would like to get those dates back the way they were originally.

Comment: The original dates are not modified they are still shown in column `A`, column `C` is just a working column to allow the identification of the duplicated ones, you can hide columns `C` and `D` afterwards. Use column `D` to filter and delete "Duplicated" records. Do let me know of any other concerns you might have...

Comment: Any news, It worked? If so please acknowledge the answer... Else let me know is there is any problem...

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you. Sorry it's away